# How to initialize variable inside HandleFunc in gorilla/mux package

Tags: go, mux

I had a handlerfunc:

```
    r.HandleFunc("/getstatus_a/{price}", getStatusWithPrice).Methods("GET")
```

`price` is `int` variable, I need to initialize it inside path. How can I do that?

P.S. In `getStatusWithPrice()` `price` used as an argument that transmit in sql request.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved

```
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    price := vars["price"]
```